# ASP.NET Get value from DropDownList in EditItemTemplate in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView that I have placed in DropDownList's in 2 columns.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upgrade" SortExpression="Upgrade">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelUpgrade" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Upgrade") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUpgrade" runat="server" Width="100px">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="6">5</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

how do I grab the item from ddlUpgrade in the codebehind?

OnUpdating Event - I don't have a way to pull the row to get the value from the drop down but I add my sql parameters here.

```
 protected void IAP_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e){}
```

RowUpdating Event - I can get the row here but I can't add the value to the sql parameters because e.command isn't valid here

```
protected void gvClients_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow _row = gvClients.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        DropDownList _ddl = (DropDownList)_row.FindControl("ddlUpgrade");
        SqlParameter _parm = new SqlParameter("@Upgrade", _ddl.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Where is ddlNewUpdate?

Comment: HA ok so 1st I'm grabbing the wrong dropdownlist, 2nd, how do I grab the item from ddlUpgrade in codebehind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the RowUpdating event you can capture the control inside the edit template based on its ID.

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlUpgrade");

SqlParameter _parm = new SqlParameter("@Upgrade", ddl.SelectedItem.ToString());
    e.Command.Parameters.Add(_parm);
```

Comment: RowUpdating GridViewUpdateEventArgs e doesn't contain e.Command

Comment: Can you paste the entire OnRowUpdating method?

Comment: The event for OnUpdating only has SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e which I can't pull the row from to find the dropdownlist but this is where I am adding my sqlparameters. The RowUpdatining event has GridViewUpdateEventArgs e which I can pull the row from but it doesn't have the ability to add sqlparameters

Comment: Is the OnUpdating event attached to a SqlDataSource?

Comment: Thats kind of separate from this question. With some more context I could probably help.

Comment: Yes it's attached to a SqlDataSource

Comment: This did point me in the right direction and I have everything working with a few tricks.

Answer (score 2):

I would add a hidden field outside the GridView:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelection" value="" runat="server" />
```

And change the gvClients_RowUpdating method:

```
protected void gvClients_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow _row = gvClients.Rows[e.RowIndex];        
    DropDownList _ddl = _row.FindControl("ddlUpgrade") as DropDownList;

    if(_ddl != null)
    {
        hdnSelection.Value = _ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
        IAP.Update();//Assuming IAP is the ID of the SqlDataSource
    }

}
```

And my IAP_Updating method should look like this:

```
protected void IAP_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    SqlParameter _parm = new SqlParameter("@Upgrade", hdnSelection.Value);
    e.Command.Parameters.Add(_parm);
}
```

I did not test the code. You may need to tweak.